# Reference a FQCN with ::class in Symfony config

Tags: php, symfony

I'd like to pass an array of class names as an argument to one of my services. My Symfony config looks like:

```yaml
services:
  command.bus.my_middleware:
    class: App\Infrastructure\CommandBus\Middleware\MyMiddleware
    arguments:
      $ignoredExceptions:
        - 'App\Exception\DownloadException'
        - 'App\Exception\InvalidImageException'
```

This works fine, however, I'd like to get compile-time insurance that the referenced class names exist. So I tried this:

```yaml
    arguments:
      $ignoredExceptions:
        - !php/const App\Exception\DownloadException::class
        - !php/const App\Exception\InvalidImageException::class
```

But this doesn't work, as `::class` is not a real constant:

> The file "/app/config/services/messaging.yaml" does not contain valid YAML: The constant "App\Exception\DownloadException::class" is not defined at line 50

**Is there a way to provide a FQCN, that will fail to compile if the class name does not exist?**

Comment: FWIW, even in a plain PHP file where it works, ::class doesn't require the class to exist - it just resolves the name based on the current namespace and use statements, and substitutes in the resulting string, while compiling the individual file.

Comment: @IMSoP good point, that wouldn't solve my problem anyway.